# Promise.All for a list of images

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code, which fetches from a list of URLs in imagesList and then adds the images to Dropzone box. My problem is that images appear in a rather random order in the Dropzone box, and NOT in the order in imagesList.

I am aware maybe this can be fixed if I were to use Promise.All, but I am not sure how to code the following in Promise.All. I have tried a long time but all failed to work.

Please help.

```
  var imagesList = ["/img1.jpg", "/img2.jpg", "/img3.jpg"];

  for (var i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {
              let name = imagesList[i];
              name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

              fetch(imagesList[i])
                    .then(res => res.blob())
                    .then(blob => {
                    let file = new File([blob], name, blob);
                    myDropzone1.addFile(file);
              });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how you could do it.

Basically, for each url in `imagesList`, you produce a `Promise`.
You put all those promises in `Promise.all`, which will return another promise when all the images are loaded, and it will iterate with the order passed in.

```
var imagesList = ["/img1.jpg", "/img2.jpg", "/img3.jpg"];
Promise.all(imagesList.map(url => {
          const name = url.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          return fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.blob())
                .then(blob => new File([blob], name, blob)
          });
})).then(results => results.forEach(file => myDropzone1.addFile(file)));
```

Please check [the documentation of Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and feel free to ask questions if you need some clarifications.

Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help.

```js
function getFile(item) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    let name = item.substring(item.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    fetch(item)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let file = new File([blob], name, blob);
      resolve(file);
    });
  })
}

let imagesList = ["/img1.jpg", "/img2.jpg", "/img3.jpg"];
let promises = imagesList.map(item => getFile(item));

Promise
.all(promises)
.then(files => {
  files.forEach(file => myDropzone1.addFile(file));
})
```